# Customize Emacs Ruby Mode for PuppetLabs conifguration

Tags: emacs, ruby, puppet

I predominantly use emacs for editing my [Puppet configuration files](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/2.7.0/type.html). 
I use the following settings in my .emacs to load Ruby mode and use it for Puppet config files (`*.pp`):

```
(autoload 'ruby-mode "ruby-mode" "Major mode for editing ruby scripts." t)
(setq auto-mode-alist  (cons '(".rb$" . ruby-mode) auto-mode-alist))
(setq auto-mode-alist  (cons '(".pp$" . ruby-mode) auto-mode-alist))
```

This works well except for the the indentation of the 'ensure' directive in my puppet files.
Because `ensure` is a reserved word in Ruby, it outdents it:

```
cron { logrotate:
  command => "/usr/sbin/logrotate",
  user => root,
  hour => 2,
ensure => present
  minute => 0,
}
```

How do I tell Emacs to not treat `ensure` specially in Puppet files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest way to handle this is to just copy ruby-mode.el
to puppet-mode.el and rip out all the places you see it handling
`ensure` specially. In my `ruby-mode.el`, this seems to only happen in two places:

1. Where the block words are defined

   ```
   (defconst ruby-block-mid-keywords
     '("then" "else" "elsif" "when" "rescue" "ensure")
     "Keywords where the indentation gets shallower in middle of block statements.")
   ```
2. Where reserved words are defined:

   ```
   (defconst ruby-font-lock-keywords
   ...
                "ensure"
   ```

I bet deleting `ensure` from those two places, saving as `puppet-mode.el` and then changing your `.emacs` to this would do the trick:

```
(autoload 'puppet-mode "puppet-mode" "Major mode for editing Puppet config" t)
(setq auto-mode-alist  (cons '(".pp$" . puppet-mode) auto-mode-alist))
```

Comment: This worked well. I wasn't very happy with the emacs-puppet module available and this worked well. I also needed to do a replace-string for 'ruby-mode' / 'puppet-mode' in order to make this function as desired.